# Hover over another div on a image will interrupt my onmouseenter

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, onmouseover

https://github.com/UneSaltedFish/landingpage.git  (github link to view full html/css/js)

Here I am developing a landing page, and On the right bar vector picture, I used a hover effect(When I enter this pic, It will change to another picture and there will have two clickable text on it.)

```
<div class="rightCon">
   <img onmouseenter="right2()" onmouseleave="right1()" src="right.png" alt="right" class="right" id = "right">
   <div id= "right1" class = "text"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/"><pre>  2000<br>ARCHIVAL<br>  SITE<br></pre></a></div>
   <div id= "right2" class = "text"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/"><pre>  2012<br>ARCHIVAL<br>  SITE<br></pre></a></div>
</div>
```

and it is looks like this.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lTUn.png)

Here is the css code:

```
a{
 color:black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.rightCon {
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
}
#right1{
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
 left:850px;
 top:150px;
 opacity: 0;
}
#right2{
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
 left:853px;
 top:350px;
 opacity: 0;
}
.text{
 font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

and the js code

```
 function right2(){
 document.getElementById("right").src = "right2.png";
 document.getElementById("right1").style.opacity=1;
 document.getElementById("right2").style.opacity=1;
}
function right1(){
 document.getElementById("right").src = "right.png";
 document.getElementById("right1").style.opacity=0;
 document.getElementById("right2").style.opacity=0;
}
```

The problem is the onmouseenter is work when go in to right area, but when I go in to right1 and right 2 area, onmouseleave is work, which I don't want to. I want this hover only work when enter right and leave right.

After I search online, I try to make div as a child of img but I don't know How to make children of a img.And I am stuck here.

Thank you in advance for all help.

Comment: so the events should be on the wrapping div, not the image.

Comment: And this requires no JavaScript, simple css selectors could do this

Comment: Thank you!!!! It works!  I've stuck in here for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the events to be on the image and the other siblings, you should put the event listeners on their parent. Now anywhere you hover in the parent, the mouse will remain.

```
<div class="rightCon" nmouseenter="right2()" onmouseleave="right1()">
  <img o src="right.png" alt="right" class="right" id = "right">
  ...
```

Other option just pure css

```css
.rightCon .details { 
  display: none;
}

.rightCon:hover .default { 
  display: none;
}

.rightCon:hover .details { 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightCon">
   <img class="default" src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200">
   <img class="details" src="http://placekitten.com/400/200">
   <div class="default">FOOOOOO</div>
   <div class="details">Meow</div>
</div>
```